# Note being played twice in jfugue

Tags: jfugue

My code is as follows:
player.play("C");
It plays the note C, but twice. I wasn't getting it at first. After running the code multiple times, it started giving this glitch.

Comment: This was a bug in JFugue v5.0.5. Try downloading a newer version, and let me know if you still have the problem.

Comment: Thank you sir.. It worked. Can you also tell me if Jfugue can work in android?

Comment: As of Android Marshmallow, Android now supports MIDI. However, I have not released an official version of JFugue for Android at this point. I would really appreciate help from the open source community on JFugue + Android.

Comment: Thank you sir for your help. Your work in jfugue is truly awesome...

Comment: Thank you! I'm very glad that you are enjoying JFugue. That's why I made it - so others can have fun and enjoy creating musical programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update jfugue to the latest version